# build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat8, netbeans-8

I just installed apache tomcat 8 and this error appears with I try to start the server:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestWeb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.
```

and the log file is empty.

Here is the line 1045 in build-impl.xml that has the error:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution and I am sharing it so it can be useful for someone else:

If you were searching for a solution you probably found a solution saying to go to`C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.36-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\bin`
then open `catalina.bat` on Notepad++ and search for `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"` and `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%"` and remove the double quotes.

but for some of people this might not be enough you might also need to search for  `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JSSE_OPTS%"` and remove the double quotes from here two and the server will run probably.

Comment: it works, but do you know why? what is the reason for it?

Comment: I don't really know why exactly, but as I found it is part of the configurations to help Apache access Java virtual machine, I am not 100% sure but this what I found.

Comment: I couldn't find this

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the owner of the Tomcat directory. On Linux or BSD do this:

```
chown -R username /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/
```

Make sure to use the path to your Tomcat directory